# Capturing the data in context on exceptions using log4net

Tags: log4net

How I can capture the input parameters of the method that caused the exception using **log4net**?

Currently I'm using the **log4net**'s `GlobalContext` in every method to store the input parameters and through a custom exception layout I'm logging the context data to database.

Is there any other better strategy I can apply here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would consider using a framework for aspect oriented development, you could have a look at this post:
[Method Tracing Using log4net and PostSharp](http://michaelfcollins3.me/2010/10/method-tracing-using-log4net-and-postsharp/)

There are other frameworks that should work fine with log4net i.e. AspectF, Unity, Spring.Net but I have not tried them.

Comment: I've no idea about Aspect Oriented Programming, will definitely have a look at that.